# CoffeeScript get key/value error from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

Here is my json string:

```
{
    "long-url":"http://a.longlongurl.com";
}
```

parse json string:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse json_str
alert(jsonObj.long-url);
```

error: `ReferenceError: url is not defined`. Looks like `-` in the key make this error. How to get value if the key has a `minus` in it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subtracting `url` from `jsonObj.long`.
That's not what you want to do.

Instead, use indexer notation:

```
jsonObj["long-url"]
```